# Refinery CMS - How to resize a resource image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I have a `TestimonialResource` model which has a `resource` field type. The backend works okay where I am able to pick a file to upload as a `resource` to the testimonial.

However, I am unable to generate a thumbnail of the resource(if it is an image). I know it works with an `image` field type and have done it in the past.

I have also looked at the available methods in the Rails console and it does list `thumb` as a method.

However, the following does not work in the front-end view.

```
<%= testimonial_resource.content.thumb('400x400#').url %>
```

Content is the RefineryCMS resource.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

> Dragonfly stores an image once and produces image variations (thumbnails, formats and enhancements) on-the-fly.

So, all related methods are available only to the image model. That means you can't run those methods on everything, but you have a link or local address to the image. So, you can always build a thumb manually:

```
require "mini_magick"

image = MiniMagick::Image.open("input.jpg")
image.resize "400x400"
image.format "png"
image.write "output.png"
```

For the existing [image object](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/images/app/helpers/refinery/admin/images_helper.rb):

```
image.thumbnail(:geometry => '400x400#c').url
```